# Replace all (/.) parameters with equation or condition rather than single values

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

Suppose that one wants to calculate the surface charge density of a polarized dielectric ellipsoid, prolate ellipsoid with long and short axes as $a$ and $c$ where $a$ is parallel to the $z$ axis. $a$ and $c$ are defined variables. Having the polarization, $\bf P$, we have the surface charge density as $\sigma={\bf P}.n$, where $n$ is the normal unit vector to the surface of the ellipsoid. Assume that $\bf P$ is a vector parallel to $z$ axis, maybe unit vector.
Now the surface charge density reads

```
n[x_, y_, z_] := 1/Sqrt[((2 x)/c^2)^2 + ((2 y)/c^2)^2 + ((2 z)/a^2)^2] {(2 x)/c^2, (2 y)/c^2, (2 z)/a^2 };
P = UnitVector[3, 3];
σ[x_, y_, z_] :=  Dot[P, n[x, y, z]] /. {x, y, x} -> z^2/a^2 + x^2/c^2 + y^2/c^2 == 1;
```

but it, $\sigma $, does not have the correct functionality and the charge distribution is not limited to the ellipsoidal surface; it is over volume (all space). How can I correct the replacement (/.) when I have an equation rather than values?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with the replacement rule? I can't figure out exactly what you're expecting this to do. Can you give the desired output perhaps?

Comment: @march, Thank you. Actually, I would like to calculate the value of the inner product of two vectors over a surface. The surface here is an ellipsoid surface. The result is surface charge density as it sounds, it is non-zero, or it is defined, just on the ellipsoidal surface and it must be zero everywhere ales. I hope it makes it more clear. Now I am wondering how can I find this value using the replace all command in Mathematica or by any other methods that I am not aware of it.

Comment: So really this question is about how to do a surface integral of the function over the surface of an ellipsoid? Probably you will need to specify values for `a`, `b`, and `c` in order to do this, but if I can find the time, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @march, Thanks again. Yes, we have the values for $a$, $b=c$. It is kind of conditional evaluation.